# C# Trying to save a picture from a user in a web browser

Tags: c#, html, file, input, variable-declaration

I am trying to allow a user to insert a file and then send it in an email, but I don't know how to receive that file. There is an error on the "System.IO.File" part of my code that says "static types cannot be used as return types" I am not sure what to do from here, I have tried looking that up but I'm not sure.

C# Class

```
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        [Display(Name = "Picture of Product sticker")]
  error ->      public System.IO.File strFileName { get; set; }
```

HTML

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="strFileName"></label>
            <input asp-for="strFileName" type="file" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="strFileName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: `System.IO.File` is a static type. Judging by the name of the property, did you mean for it to be a `string`?

Comment: @gunr2171 that would just grab the name of the file. Wouldn't I need more than that?

Comment: I think what you want to use is `HttpPostedFileBase`